# Link disappears in IE 6 and 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, element

I have link (button actually) inside a TD, but its completely hidden in IE 6 and 7:

```
.btn-delete {
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    height: 31px;
    text-indent: -1000em;
    background:#dd0 url(../img/button.png) no-repeat;
    /*.float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

...but if I add `float:left` to it, it shows fine. How do I fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that the text-indent is what is causing this behavior.

In the past, I've used an image button with the value set to the same value as the original button, with a transparent image so that the background image can be used:

`<input type="image" class="btn-delete" value="Delete" src="spacer.gif" />`